# Is there a way to give auto generated value(incremental integer) to a value in Dictionary key value pair In C#

Tags: c#

Created a dictionary with key as string and value as integer.

My code is as follows. Let's consider `s` is a string in `foreach(string s in wordarray)`

```
Dictionary<string,int> wordmap = new Dictionary<string,int>();
wordmap.Add(s, GetValueOrDefault(s, 0) + 1);
```

Please provide solution to add auto incremented values for the dictionary

Comment: How about you keep `int count = 0;` outside the `foreach` loop and increment it in every iteration of `foreach`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you cant use GetValueOrDefault(s,0) that is mistake.Because this function accept just one parameter
You dont need to use it when you add value to dictionary.If you want to add value to dictionary you can create a variable such as default 0 and you increment and add to dictionary below;

```
Dictionary<string, int> wordmap = new Dictionary<string, int>();
int value = 0;
foreach (string s in wordarray)
{
    wordmap.Add(s, value);
    value += 1;
}
```